# Unable to retrieve cert chain Python

Tags: python, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I have this code just as a tester for another program that I am trying to write and this does not pull the cert.

```
    import socket, ssl, pprint


    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    ssl_sock = ssl.wrap_socket(s,
                               ca_certs="etc/ca_certs_file",
                               cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED)
    ssl_socket.connect (('www.google.com', 443))

    pprint.pprint(ssl_sock.getpeercert())

    ssl_sock.close()
```

The code that I have for my other project can not grab the cert chain with the following code..

```
    def get_peer_cert_chain(host, port):
        try:
            port = int(port)
            ctx = OpenSSL.SSL.Context(OpenSSL.SSL.SSLv23_METHOD)
            sock = OpenSSL.SSL.Connection(ctx, socket.socket())
            SSLSocket.connect((host, port))
            SSLSocket.do_handshake()
            SSLSocket.getpeercert(binary_form=False)
            return sock.get_peer_cert_chain()
        except:
            print('INFO: Unable to retrieve certificate chain from ' + str(host) + ':' + str(port))
            exit(1)


    def cert_chain_interpreter(host, port, chain):
        if chain != None:
            output_csv = open(args.output,"a")
            writer = csv.writer(output_csv)
            for cert in chain:
                x509Name = OpenSSL.crypto.X509.get_subject(cert)
                PKey = OpenSSL.crypto.X509.get_pubkey(cert)
                issuer = OpenSSL.crypto.X509.get_issuer(cert)
                writer_data = [host, port, OpenSSL.crypto.X509Name.get_components(x509Name), OpenSSL.crypto.X509.has_expired(cert), OpenSSL.crypto.X509.get_notBefore(cert), OpenSSL.crypto.X509.get_notAfter(cert), OpenSSL.crypto.X509Name.get_components(issuer), OpenSSL.crypto.X509.get_signature_algorithm(cert), OpenSSL.crypto.X509.get_serial_number(cert), OpenSSL.crypto.X509.get_version(cert), OpenSSL.crypto.PKey.bits(PKey)]
        writer.writerow(writer_data)
    output_csv.close()
```

This code prints out unable to retrieve certificate chain.